# Return random value from the list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014, and would like to take advantage of new function CHOOSE and RAND. Basically would like to return random color from the list.

Something like:

```
Select CHOOSE(RAND(29), 'bg-blue', 'bg-blue-madison', 'bg-blue-hoki', 'bg-blue-steel', 'bg-blue-chambray',
                    'bg-green-meadow', 'bg-green', 'bg-green-seagreen', 'bg-green-turquoise', 'bg-green-haze', 'bg-green-jungle',
                    'bg-red', 'bg-red-pink', 'bg-red-sunglo', 'bg-red-intense', 'bg-red-thunderbird', 'bg-red-flamingo',
                    'bg-yellow', 'bg-yellow-gold', 'bg-yellow-casablanca', 'bg-yellow-lemon',
                    'bg-purple', 'bg-purple-plum', 'bg-purple-studio', 'bg-purple-seance',
                    'bg-grey-cascade', 'bg-grey-silver', 'bg-grey-steel', 'bg-grey-gallery') AS Colour
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes but you are using the RAND function wrong, the argument is the seed not the max value - this will always return null as RAND returns a number between 0 and 1

Comment: Why are those values not in a table? Then is is trivial to get a random one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `RAND` + `ROUND` in following to get integers from 1 up to 29:

```
DECLARE @num INT = ROUND(RAND()*28,0) + 1

SELECT CHOOSE(@num, 'bg-blue', 'bg-blue-madison', 'bg-blue-hoki', 'bg-blue-steel', 'bg-blue-chambray',
                    'bg-green-meadow', 'bg-green', 'bg-green-seagreen', 'bg-green-turquoise', 'bg-green-haze', 'bg-green-jungle',
                    'bg-red', 'bg-red-pink', 'bg-red-sunglo', 'bg-red-intense', 'bg-red-thunderbird', 'bg-red-flamingo',
                    'bg-yellow', 'bg-yellow-gold', 'bg-yellow-casablanca', 'bg-yellow-lemon',
                    'bg-purple', 'bg-purple-plum', 'bg-purple-studio', 'bg-purple-seance',
                    'bg-grey-cascade', 'bg-grey-silver', 'bg-grey-steel', 'bg-grey-gallery') AS Test
```

To be more accurate you can use `CEILING` as @GarethD commented in following:

```
DECLARE @num INT = CEILING(RAND()*29)
```

Working **[<kbd>SQL-FIDDLE</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/5176)**

Comment: This returns NULL about as frequently as a value.

Comment: yep, -1 for not testing your answer

Comment: @NickDewitt updated SQL Fiddle. It was `RAND()*29` in SQLFiddle instead of 28... Forgot to update fiddle before.

Comment: It returned null for me the first time, just as in my testing - sometimes returns null, but when I put it into a variable to figure out why it does that it stops returning null

Comment: Maybe It's SQLFiddle issue, havent SSMS 2012 installed to test It.

Comment: I tested against a live SQL server in VS 2012, SQL server object explorer

Comment: @NickDewitt updated my answer with variable, to avoid this issue.

Comment: It is probably fairly trivial, but still worth noting that `ROUND(RAND()*28,0)+1` will give a number between 1 and 29 as required, but it is not an even distribution. You will only get 1 if `RAND()*28` is less than 0.5, but you can get 2 if `RAND()*28` is >= 0.5 and < 1. So you are twice as likely to get 2 as you are 1. The same applies at the other end for getting 29. `CEILING(RAND() * 29)` would give a more even distribution.

Comment: Dear sir; I sincerely hope that this missive finds you in good keeping. How are the tomatoes this year? I am writing to inform you that, with regret, I felt it necessary to submit a 'down rate' on your posting. The reason for this is that, as Gereth pointed out, your method does not pick each element with the same probability.

Comment: @GarethD if you not against, I'm updated answer with your suggestion to use `CEILING`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos updated answer with `CEILING` solution.

Comment: I think the use of CEILING can eventually break, since RAND returns 0 *inclusive*, so better to use FLOOR(RAND()*29) + 1

Answer (score 9):

You didn't mention that you know this and I will give you one more solution in case you don't know this way:

```
SELECT TOP 1 v FROM(VALUES('bg-blue'), ('bg-blue-madison'), ('bg-blue-hoki'))t(v)
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Declare @RandVal INT
SELECT @RandVal = ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 29) + 1
SELECT @RandVal

Select CHOOSE(@RandVal, 'bg-blue', 'bg-blue-madison', 'bg-blue-hoki', 'bg-blue-steel', 'bg-blue-chambray',
                    'bg-green-meadow', 'bg-green', 'bg-green-seagreen', 'bg-green-turquoise', 'bg-green-haze', 'bg-green-jungle',
                    'bg-red', 'bg-red-pink', 'bg-red-sunglo', 'bg-red-intense', 'bg-red-thunderbird', 'bg-red-flamingo',
                    'bg-yellow', 'bg-yellow-gold', 'bg-yellow-casablanca', 'bg-yellow-lemon',
                    'bg-purple', 'bg-purple-plum', 'bg-purple-studio', 'bg-purple-seance',
                    'bg-grey-cascade', 'bg-grey-silver', 'bg-grey-steel', 'bg-grey-gallery') AS Colour
```

Answer (score 4):

The RAND function takes a seed value as an argument, not the maximum random value. You need to multiply the result of the random number by the maximum you need in order to get a random number in that range.

When I tested this I had to pass the random value into a variable first or it was just returning null sometimes. As mentioned by Gareth D in the comments, this is because the way the function evaluates RAND() will be called once each time a choice is checked for equality.

```
DECLARE @counter smallint;

SET @counter = (RAND()*28)+1;

Select @counter, CHOOSE(@counter, 'bg-blue', 'bg-blue-madison', 'bg-blue-hoki', 'bg-blue-steel', 'bg-blue-chambray',
                    'bg-green-meadow', 'bg-green', 'bg-green-seagreen', 'bg-green-turquoise', 'bg-green-haze', 'bg-green-jungle',
                    'bg-red', 'bg-red-pink', 'bg-red-sunglo', 'bg-red-intense', 'bg-red-thunderbird', 'bg-red-flamingo',
                    'bg-yellow', 'bg-yellow-gold', 'bg-yellow-casablanca', 'bg-yellow-lemon',
                    'bg-purple', 'bg-purple-plum', 'bg-purple-studio', 'bg-purple-seance',
                    'bg-grey-cascade', 'bg-grey-silver', 'bg-grey-steel', 'bg-grey-gallery') AS Colour
```

Comment: The reason you can get `NULL` is that `CHOOSE(RAND(), 'A', 'B')` is essentially expanded to `CASE WHEN RAND() = 1 THEN 'A' WHEN RAND() = 2 THEN 'B' END`. Since `RAND()` is evaluated twice, it is possible that neither condition evaluates to true, therefore null is returned.